# Finding continuous functions $f$ with property that $f(x)\in \mathbb Q$ if and only if $f(x+1)\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

The question is to find such continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ which have the property that $f(x)\in \mathbb Q$ if and only if $f(x+1)\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$?

I tried to solve this question as follows:

I'll try to prove that such a function does not exist. Suppose on the contrary that such a function $f$ exists. Then,

One observation is that $f$ can't be a constant, and $f$ can't attain only rational or only irrational values.  So $f$ must attain irrational and rational values both.

Let $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be defined as $g(x)=f(x)+f(x+1)$. It follows that $g$ is continuous and that it attains only irrational values (proof: for any $x$, Case 1: $f(x)$ is rational. In this case $f(x+1)$ must be irrational hence $g(x)$ is irrational. Case 2: $f(x)$ is irrational. In this case $f(x+1)$ must be rational else the hypothesis will be violated. Again, $g(x)$ is irrational.)

Hence by IVT, $g$ must be an irrational constant. That is, $$g(x)=s$$, where $s$ is a fixed irrational number.

Now, for all $x\in \mathbb R$,  $g(x)=g(x+1)$ which gives $ f(x)=f(x+2)$ which implies that $f$ must be a periodic function.

It follows that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$ and attains its maximum value on $[0,2]$.

Define $h(x):=f(x)f(x+1)$. $h$ is continuous and using the hypothesis, it follows that $h$ attains only irrational values so by IVT as before, $h$ must be an irrational constant. Let $h(x)=s'$, where $s'$ is a fixed irrational number.

Now, $|f(x)-f(x+1)|^2=g(x)^2-4h(x)=s^2-4s'\gt 0$ that is $$s^2\gt 4s' \tag 1$$

Let $L=\{x: f(x)\lt f(x+1)\}, R=\{x: f(x)\gt f(x+1)\}$.

For all $x\in L$, It follows that $-f(x)+f(x+1)=\sqrt{s^2-4s'}$.
Adding $g(x)$ on both sides to get:
$$2f(x+1)=s+\sqrt{s^2-4s'}\implies 2s-2f(x)=s+\sqrt{s^2-4s'}\implies 2f(x)=s-\sqrt{s^2-4s'}$$

For all $x\in R$, it follows that $-f(x+1)+f(x)=\sqrt{s^2-4s'}$. Adding $g(x)$ on both sides gives: $2f(x)=s+\sqrt{s^2-4s'}$.

$f[0,2]$ must be a closed and bounded interval. But $f[0,2]=\{s-\sqrt{s^2-4s'},s+\sqrt{s^2-4s'}\}$. Hence, by continuity of $f$, $s-\sqrt{s^2-4s'}=s+\sqrt{s^2-4s'}$ which gives $\sqrt{s^2-4s'}=0$. It follows that $s^2=4s'$, which contradicts $(1)$.

Hence such a function $f$ does not exist.

Is my proof above correct? Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, can you see that $L,R$ are nonempty, disjoint open sets with $L\cup R = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Thanks a lot for comment :). I noted that L and R are disjoint but don't see how openness of L and R follows. I think there's no reason to believe that L and R are open sets. Can you please elaborate on that? Thanks.

Comment: Whenever $f,g$ are continuous, the set $\{x : f(x) < g(x)\}$ is open.  (In $\mathbb{R}$, this follows simply from the continuity of $f-g$ but it's true even in contexts when $f-g$ is nonsense)

Comment: @BrianMoehring: This is a very nice idea. Thanks a lot. Indeed, the idea is that a function $h$ continuous and non zero at a point p retains its sign in a neighbourhood of p. I think this should hold for any continuous $h:X\to \mathbb R$, where $X$ is a metric space, that is $\{x\in X: h(x)>0\}$ is open in X. Though, I don't understand how it will alternatively answer question in my post.

Comment: I've perhaps tried to abstractify the problem more than necessary, but it's due to the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$.  In present context, the corresponding argument is just that $f(x)-f(x+1)$ is negative somewhere and positive somewhere (i.e. $L,R$ are nonempty) so by the IVT, $f(x) - f(x+1) = 0$ somewhere.  Contradiction

Comment: @BrianMoehring: That's fantastic! Thank you very much. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a flaw in your argument: If $f$ takes the value zero then $h(x):=f(x)f(x+1)$ takes the value zero as well, so that the conclusion “$h$ attains only irrational values” is wrong. However, one can conclude that $h$ is constant from the fact that it takes only values in $(\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q) \cup \{ 0 \}$. The remaining argument still works in the case $h(x) = s'= 0$.

Here are two suggestions for simplification:

*Suggestion 1:* Starting with your (correct) proof that $f(x+1)+f(x)$ is constant, you can repeat the same argument to show that $f(x+1) -f(x)$ is also constant. It follows that $f$ is constant, which is impossible.

*Suggestion 2:* Start with your proof that both $f(x)+f(x+1) = s$ and $f(x)f(x+1) = t$ are constant. That means that for every $x \in \Bbb R$, $f(x)$ and $f(x+1)$ are solutions of the same quadratic equation $y^2-s y + t = 0$. It follows that $f(x)$ can only take the values $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, which again implies that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your review :). I want to say that I had realised the exemption of the case $h(x)=0$ in my post. I mentioned the same in chat also and planned to modify my post shortly. But I thought that could be fixed: if $h(x)=0$ holds for infinitely many $x$ then either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x+1)=0$ for infinite $x$. Again, I could define symbols like L and R to conclude that range f is finite, which would result in contradiction. Hence $h$ must be $0$ at finitely many points. So we can now use my argument on $]-\infty, -a]\cup [a,\infty[$ for some a?

Comment: But somehow, I didn't use the obvious fact that $f(x)-f(x+1)$ is also a constant. I don't know why I didn't use that. +1

Comment: @Brian, Koro: You are both right, $h(x)$ irrational or zero suffices to conclude that $h(x) = t$ is constant. But then you can also proceed more simply: For each $x$ are $f(x+1)$ and $f(x)$ solutions of the quadratic equation $y^2-sy+ t = 0$. It follows that $f(x)$ can only take the values $f(0)$ or $f(1)$. That should quickly lead to a contradiction.

Comment: An observation: Claim: h can’t be zero anywhere. First let’s agree that h is not identically 0 (for, then f(x) =0 on a subset P of R and f(x+1)=0 for x in R\P, subtracting g gives f(x) irrational constant on R\P. In all f attains two values only -0 and s, which contradicts continuity.) Suppose that h(a)=0 then it can be shown that h attains either 0 and some irrational value(s). This again violates IVT, hence a contradiction. (Here we can’t say h is a constant as h(a)=0 also but the constant can’t be 0). So h can’t attain 0 at all as it violates the “contradiction assumption” at the start.

Comment: That is, can I say that my assumption: “h attains only irrational values” under the “contradiction assumption” at the beginning of my post, is not flawed? Mr. @BrianMoehring and Mr. Martin R, I would request your views on this please.

Comment: @Koro Your initial assumption is a contradiction (this is what we wanted to show and what we've shown), so it hardly makes sense to talk about the truth value of a statement under that assumption.  What's important is whether the argument is valid, and you had stated "h attains only irrational values" with no reasoning.  That's what makes it flawed.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: For my own understanding, I want to understand that:  We assumed something (a statement on the contrary) then under that assumption we applied some arguments A1, A2,…, An etc. Now at some point (not at the end), we get two mutually exclusive options: either yes or no. Then, under the initial assumption only, we’ll make a decision (let’s forget about the end result for a while). So my argument is “incomplete” and not “flawed”?

Comment: Also, if h attained a zero at any point, I think that it can’t be concluded that h is a constant. What will that constant be: either 0 (which we have shown is not possible) or an irrational number, which is again not possible).

Comment: @Koro: $h$ is constant for the same reason that $g$ is constant: If $h$ takes two distinct values $a$ and $b$ (both irrational or $a=0$ and $b$ irrational) then it must also take a real value $c$ between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @MartinR: h is not identically $0$ (we can show this) so let's forget about this. Now suppose that h attains $0$ at some a that is $h(a)=0$.So at all points where $h$ is non-zero, h is irrational. That is $h$ attains irrational values and $0$ (in this case), hence by continuity $h$ must be a constant say c. So h(x)=c for all x, $h(a)=0$ implies c=0 hence $h(x)=0$ for all $x$ which is a contradiction as h is not identically zero. So the only case that is left for exhaustion is the case when $h$ attains only irrational values. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, then I think second line in answer "h takes values in $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q \cup \{0\}$ " is not required that is, $h$ takes only irrational values (under the initial assumption) should suffice. If "it can be shown that $h$ takes only irrational values" were added in my post, then my post would be complete. So the conclusion that "h takes only irrational values" is not wrong, I think. Mr. Martin, is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Koro: It is correct, but too complicated in my opinion: If $h$ takes only values in $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q \cup \{0\}$ then it must be constant, because of the IVT. For the rest of your proof it does not matter if that constant is zero or some irrational number.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Martin for the clarifications. **One last question**: My conclusion that "h attains only irrationals" was not wrong, rather the proof missed the detail why $h$ attained only irrational values. Had that detail been incorporated in the proof, then the proof would have been considered complete in totality.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Koro: As I pointed out, you did not prove that $h$ takes only irrational values. And yes, you can fix that detail, and everything else looks OK. But, as I tried to explain, *it does not matter* if the constant ($s'$ in your proof) is zero or not.